# How to submit values to backend and receive the results using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am using the following jquery code to receive the values
and validate the values which perfectly works. Then send them to my java application and receive the responses, but it does not send the requests to the specified method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#reg').click(function(){
                    $('#signup').show('fast');
                });
                $('#register').click(function(){
                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var family = $("#family").val();
                    if(name.length <= 1)
                    {
                        $("#messageSent").text("name is invalid");
                    }
                    else if(family.length <= 1){
                            $("#messageSent").text("family is invalid");
                    }else{
                        var data = 'name=' + name & 'family='+ family;
                          $.ajax({
                              type:"GET",
                              cache:false,
                              url:"http://localhost:8080/myApp/register.jsp",
                              data : data,
                              success:function(html){
                                  $("#messageSent").html(html);
                              }
                          });
                          return false;
                         }

                    });
                });
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery's ajax implementation if you're already using jQuery?

Comment: Firstly, you should do the validation before sending the request. If you add the validation where you have it in the source, the validation will not run till the form has been submitted.

Comment: @jSang, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another jsp file and put the results in that Then call the controller from the first page and provide the new jsp file in a div of your primary page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "nameOfAction",
    data:"name=" + name + "family=" + email,
    dataType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#nameOfDive").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is what you need to do

1) **How do I pass the values of the form to the validate function?**

Answer: You dont need to pass the values the validate function can fetch the values of form elements. Here is how you can do it.

```
var name=$("name").val();
var family=$("family").val();
```

Once you get all the values you can do what every you want to validate it.

2) **How do I show an error or a confirmation? (so the form should not be hidden once submitted).**

Answer: You can create a div and set its css property display:hidden. If your validation function doesnt validate the form you can make this div visible and show the error inside it.

```
<div id="merror" style="display:none"></div>
```

Then in your validation function

```
$("merror").show();
$("merror").html("The form validation failed, please try again");
```

3) **Is there any other alternative to my method?**

Answer: If you are already using jquery use jquery $.post to post the data and not the regular javascript ajax methods. The benefit of using jquery methods is that its cross browser compatible and much easier to use.

One more thing. You should show the confirmation when you receive the response form the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery validate for validating the form.

Refer this link for more information : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Please find the updated answer. Hope it helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registrationform').hide();
    $('#registrationBtn').click(function () {
        $('#registrationform').show();
    });
});

function saveForm() {
    $("#registrationform").validate({
        rules: {
            //add rules for validation here
            name : "required"
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            //ajax code to execute if form is successfully validated
            var request = $("#registrationform").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: request,
                dataType:"json",
                async:false,
                success: function(response){    
                    $('#registrationform').hide();                                                           
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){                     
                }
            });            
        },
        messages : {
            //error messages to display
            name : "Please enter the name"
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" id="registrationBtn" name="registrationBtn" value="Register"/>
<form id="registrationform">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" onclick="saveForm();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: one the answers provides a complete example of your solution but the problem is that when I submit incorrect inputs it shows the alert and hide the form but I need it to be shown all the time and just be invisible when it is successfully submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use AJAX jQuery? "$.ajax({});"

I hope I helped.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#register').submit(function() {
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var family = $('#family').val();
      if($.trim(name) == '' || $.trim(family) == '') {
         alert('You can not leave fields blank. Sorry.');
      } else {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form.php',
            beforeSend: function() {
               // function while sending...
            },
            success: function(data) {
               // function if success. "data" returns the response
            },
            error: function() {
               // Create function for errors in the page request.
            }
         });
      }
   });
});
```